# To find a solution of a simple complex eq

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the complex number x that satisfy it: $z = \sqrt{i-1}$. I could answer this equation using the polar form, but when i try to use the cartesian coordinates, i am not able to deduce it, see:

$$z = x+yi \implies z \times z = x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi= i-1$$
$$x^2 - y^2 = -1, 2xy = 1$$

This system of equation has two solutions. One is located at the first quadrant, and the other is located at the third quadrant.

But if we use the polar coordinates, we can see that the only one allowed is the one at the first quadrant. So how to show this in the cartesian coordinate?

The only "condition" i can see would be $z>0$, since it is a square root but this make no sense for a complex number. Any help?

Comment: In complex numbers, there are two "square roots", three "cube roots" etc. A preference is often accorded to the "principal value" within a restricted range of arguments, but there's no reason the other values are less valid.

Answer (score 1):

By polar coordinates, $z^2 = -1 + i = \sqrt 2e^{i(\frac{3\pi}4 + 2k\pi)}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Taking the square root, $z = 2^{\frac 14}e^{i(\frac{3\pi}8 + k\pi)}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

In Cartesian form, the two unique solutions correspond to $k = 0,1$ which are $2^{\frac 14} \cos \frac{3\pi}8 + i2^{\frac 14}\sin \frac{3\pi}8$ and $2^{\frac 14} \cos \frac{11\pi}8 + i2^{\frac 14}\sin \frac{11\pi}8$. Since the first value has an argument in the first quadrant, it is often given preference as the principal value, but as I mentioned in my comment, there is no reason the other in the third quadrant is any less valid. You will arrive at the same two roots if you use the method of algebraic expansion and comparison of coefficients.

Comment: Yes, but x² = -1 + i is a different equation from x = \sqrt{-1+i}. That's why i am complaining about it. It is like to find the solution of x = \sqrt{a}, you can quadratic both sides to find two solutions, but only one is valid.

I think i disagree your comment "two unique solution", see:
$x = re^{i\theta} \implies$
$re^{i\theta} = \sqrt{-1+i} = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}e^{i(3\pi/4 + 2k\pii)}}  = 2^{1/4}e^{i(3\pi/8 + k\pii)}}$

Comment: Yes, but x² = -1 + i is a different equation from x = \sqrt{-1+i}. That's why i am complaining about it. It is like to find the solution of x = \sqrt{a}, you can quadratic both sides to find two solutions, but only one is valid.

I think i disagree your comment "two unique solution", see:
$x = re^{i\theta} \implies$
$re^{i\theta} = \sqrt{-1+i} = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}e^{i(3\pi/4 + 2k\pii)}}  = 2^{1/4}e^{i(3\pi/8 + k\pii)}}$

Comment: @Lac The square root function is defined to return the non-negative root of a non-negative real number. That convention does *not* extend to the complex domain. In which case, it is entirely acceptable to interpret that symbol as returning multiple roots. It is also possible to interpret it as returning only the principal square root. But there is no universal convention for this, unlike in the real number case.